# apache tiles integration with spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, apache-tiles

I am very new to tiles concept.I tried to use apache tiles with spring.
I used UrlBasedViewResolver to render view.The problem is that it, rendering view multiple times in a single page.Where is my mistake ?

[image]

It sholud display once but It displays contineously,till server throws exception.below is my stacktrace

```
INFO: Mapped "{[/hello],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.controller.TestController.helloWorld()
Nov 27, 2014 3:04:08 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer setDefinitions
INFO: TilesConfigurer: adding definitions [/WEB-INF/tiles.xml]
.15:04:09.408 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.a.t.c.AbstractTilesApplicationContextFactory - Initializing Tiles2 application context. . . 
.15:04:09.424 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  o.a.t.c.AbstractTilesApplicationContextFactory - Finished initializing Tiles2 application context. 
.15:04:09.565 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] INFO  org.apache.tiles.access.TilesAccess - Publishing TilesContext for context: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.SpringTilesApplicationContextFactory$SpringWildcardServletTilesApplicationContext 
Nov 27, 2014 3:04:09 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet initServletBean
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'mvc': initialization completed in 2625 ms
Hello World, Spring 3.0!
Nov 27, 2014 3:04:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.isCommitted(ServletResponseWrapper.java:183)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.isCommitted(ServletResponseWrapper.java:183)
    at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.isCommitted(ServletResponseWrapper.java:183)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layout_jsp._jspService(layout_jsp.java:119)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:523)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:934)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:676)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:670)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.DefinitionAttributeRenderer.write(DefinitionAttributeRenderer.java:56)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layout_jsp._jspx_meth_tiles_005finsertAttribute_005f0(layout_jsp.java:145)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.jsp.layout_jsp._jspService(layout_jsp.java:81)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:584)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:523)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.JspRuntimeLibrary.include(JspRuntimeLibrary.java:934)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:676)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.include(PageContextImpl.java:670)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.include(JspTilesRequestContext.java:103)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.context.JspTilesRequestContext.dispatch(JspTilesRequestContext.java:96)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.TemplateAttributeRenderer.write(TemplateAttributeRenderer.java:44)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:690)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:644)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:627)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:321)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.DefinitionAttributeRenderer.write(DefinitionAttributeRenderer.java:56)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.write(ChainedDelegateAttributeRenderer.java:76)
    at org.apache.tiles.renderer.impl.AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.render(AbstractBaseAttributeRenderer.java:106)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:670)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:336)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.renderAttribute(InsertAttributeModel.java:210)
    at org.apache.tiles.template.InsertAttributeModel.end(InsertAttributeModel.java:126)
    at org.apache.tiles.jsp.taglib.InsertAttributeTag.doTag(InsertAttributeTag.java:311)
```

below is my code

### TestController.java

```
@Controller
public class TestController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        System.out.println(message);
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }
}
```

### app-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd">

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

### tiles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="base.definition" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/layout.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/footer.jsp" />
    </definition>

    <definition name="hello" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="hello" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp" />
    </definition>

</tiles-definitions>
```

### layout.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title><tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" /></title>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td height="30" colspan="2"><tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="250"><tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" /></td>
        <td width="350"><tiles:insertAttribute name="body" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="30" colspan="2"><tiles:insertAttribute name="footer" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

### hello.jsp

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring 3.0 MVC Series: Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    ${message}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake is in tiles.xml,here it is

```
<definition name="hello" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="hello" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp" />
</definition>
```

I should not write `<put-attribute name="title" value="hello" />`,because in hello.jsp already title is added.so the definition should be like this

```
<definition name="hello" extends="base.definition">
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/hello.jsp" />
</definition>
```